# how can i stop my function to stop adding duplicate item whenever i refresh the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I wrote a function that adds a Movie list to local storage, Whenever I reload or refresh the browser the function accepts a duplicate of the same item  clicked on.

```
   const addNewMovies = Favorite
   var drophistory=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("movies"))
  if(addNewMovies.indexOf(movies) === -1){
  addNewMovies.push(movies);
  var drophistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("movies")) || [];
  drophistory.push(movies);
  setFavorite(drophistory)
  localStorage.setItem("movies", JSON.stringify(drophistory));
}
```

Comment: So why are you not checking `drophistory` for a duplicate?

Comment: `if(drophistory.indexOf(movies) === -1){
drophistory.push(movies);`  This should do it.

Comment: Still not working.